# Accordion with checkbox in panel header

Tags: javascript, reactjs, accordion

I want to put two checkboxes in the header of a accordion.

[EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/nel_mo/rd5dv3wj/1/)

The example was done with standard HTML and JS, but I would like to achieve this using React Bootstrap.

The example given is quite easy.

```
const accordionInstance = (
  <Accordion>
    <Panel header="Collapsible Group Item #1" eventKey="1">
      Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
    </Panel>
    <Panel header="Collapsible Group Item #2" eventKey="2">
      Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
    </Panel>
    <Panel header="Collapsible Group Item #3" eventKey="3">
      Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
    </Panel>
  </Accordion>
);

ReactDOM.render(accordionInstance, mountNode);
```

But swopping the `header="Collapsible Group Item #1"`

for two check boxes, not so easy.

Ive tried this approach ( dropping the `<Panel>` tag for divs ), but I cant get it to work as per my jsfiddle example above.

```
<Accordion>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h3 class="panel-title pull-left">Header Text</h3>
      <button class="btn btn-default pull-right">New</button>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
      <p>This is the body</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</Accordion>
```

Comment: add fiddle for bootstrap code too

Comment: working on it as we speak ( bootstrap fiddle )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here is a example of a working version.](http://jsfiddle.net/nel_mo/rd5dv3wj/4/)

Only thing I would like to improve is that you can click on the whole header panel to expand or collapse the accordion panel. At this stage you can only click on the heading word to do so.

If there are any suggestions in regards to this please enlighten me.

```
<div class="bs-example">
    <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title pull-left">
                    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">Demographics</a>
                </h4>
                <div class="pull-right">
                  <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" value=""/>Admission</label>
                  <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" value=""/>Non-Admission</label>
                </div>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
                <div class="panel-body">
                  <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                    <label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="">NHS Number</label>
                    <label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="">NHS Verification</label>
                    <label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="">Weight</label>
                    <label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="">Height</label>
                    <label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="">Normal BP</label>

                  </div>
                  <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                    <label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="">NOK Details</label>
                    <label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="">NOK Address</label>
                    <label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="">Ethnic group - Local list</label>
                    <label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="">Address</label>
                    <label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="">Language</label>          
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                    <label for="usr">Custom Name:</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="usr">
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title pull-left">
                    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo">Admission</a>
                </h4>
                <div class="pull-right">
                  <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" value=""/>Admission</label>
                  <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" value=""/>Non-Admission</label>
                </div>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-body">
                  <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                    <label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="">ICU dates &amp; times</label>
                    <label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="">HDU dates &amp; times</label>
                    <label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="">CCU dates &amp; times</label>
                    <label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="">ICU/HDU discharge details</label>
                    <label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="">Time of call for ICU discharges</label>
                    <label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="">Source of admission</label>
                    <label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="">Consultant</label>
                    <label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="">Allow patient renumbering</label>
                    <label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="">Prior surgery undertaken</label>
                    <label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="">Planned admission</label>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                    <label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="">Default time of response</label>
                    <label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="">Original hospital admission date</label>
                    <label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="">Speciality enterable</label>
                    <label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="">Scored/Triggered by ward</label>
                    <label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="">NEWS Score</label>  
                    <label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="">Called for in first trigger</label>
                    <label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="">Hospital admission date</label>
                    <label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="">Location prior to source</label>
                    <label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="">Location</label>
                    <label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="">Hospital</label>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                    <label for="usr">Custom Name:</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="usr">
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title pull-left">
                    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree">Discharge</a>
                </h4>
                <div class="pull-right">
                  <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" value=""/>Admission</label>
                  <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" value=""/>Non-Admission</label>
                </div>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <p>CSS stands for Cascading Style Sheet. CSS allows you to specify various style properties for a given HTML element such as colors, backgrounds, fonts etc. <a href="http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/css-tutorial/" target="_blank">Learn more.</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <p><strong>Note:</strong> Click on the linked heading text to expand or collapse accordion panels.</p>
</div>
```